# Need to add 30 minutes timer into if condition using Js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have ecommerce website. In that for same day delivery need to order before 11. So before 30 minutes of the end time(i.e. 11) i want to show that timer section.
Below code I am trying But getting issue how to set timer functionality.

```
setInterval(function(){
    var secs = 1800;
    var date = new Date;
    // date.setTime(result_from_Date_getTime);

    var seconds = date.getSeconds();
    var minutes = date.getMinutes();
    var hour = date.getHours();

    console.log("Hour"+hour+"Minutes"+minutes+"seconds"+seconds);
    // console.log(minutes);
    // console.log(seconds);
    if(hour == 10 &&    minutes>=30)
    {
        var mins = secs / 60;
        console.log("Timer"+mins);
        $('.top-header-content1').removeClass('hide-ticker1');
        
    }
    
    else if (hour >= 11){
        console.log("hii11");
        $('.top-header-content1').addClass('hide-ticker1'); 
    }
    secs--;
    },1000);
```

If anyone have a idea , how to add time please let me know

Comment: your code would not run at all due to the `secs--;` between the `if` block and the `else if` - fix the code so it parses as valid code at least, since you didn't mention that the code isn't even parsing

Comment: the logic in your code checks if the time is between 9:30:00 and 9:59:59 and removes a class ... your question states that something should show between 10:30:00 and 11:00:00 - so, the code doesn't even match the question

Comment: If you need a thirty _minutes_ timeout, don't use javascript. There is _no_ context in which that makes sense. Use `cron` or something if you need that long a timeout on the server, and you _never_ need that long a timeout on the client.

Comment: `cron` in a browser? I think you've misunderstood the code -they want to display a timer **on the web page** in the last 30 minutes before some time (not sure which, the code contradicts the question text)

Comment: I think the `else if (hour >= 10)` should just be an `else`

Comment: @Bravo , Removed that sec-- and add below.  Same thing Need to add 30 mins timer From 10:30 to 11 . In code just time mistake , Agree but that was just bcoz i just copy paste that. Also now change the code also

Comment: why do you keep saying 10:30 to 11:00 when your code does 9:30 to 10:00? `and add below.` shouldn't it be in the `if`? anyway, the `secs` variable is completely useless

Comment: sec-- try inside if also but its not working also

Comment: oh, that wasn't the fix to your logic at all - that was so the code would run

Comment: @Bravo I understand but i am not getting how to add that timer functionality

Comment: what is "timer functionality" ... you want to calculate how many seconds between now and 10:00:00 (or 11:00:00 or whatever - seems your question states one the code tries the other - not sure why you refuse to clarify this one little issue) - anyway ... so that part is easy ... you take the target time 10:00:00 (or 11:00:00) - subtract it from the current time, and there's the difference - is that the part you're having an issue with, or is it how to put this difference on to the page?

Comment: let me ask a simple question ... do you want `secs` to tbe the number of seconds between now and 10:00:00 (or 11:00:00 whichever is the actual target)

Comment: 11:00:00 is the actual target. So after 10:30 start the timer  upto 11:00:00 its ends 30 minutes

Answer (score 0):

Hi you use this code below:

```js
 /// the counting date
var countDownDate = new Date("Jan 5, 2024 15:37:25").getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

  // Get today's date and time
  var now = new Date().getTime();

  // Find the distance between now and the count down date
  var distance = countDownDate - now;

  // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

  // Display the result in the element with id="demo"
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
  + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

  // If the count down is finished
  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
  }
}, 1000);
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code will start a `setInterval()` in which during a time window between 10:30h and 11:00h a countdown will be shown. Before 10:30h and after 11:00h different messages are shown. And after 11:00h the `setInterval` is cleared.

```js
// div for output on page:
const demo=document.getElementById("demo"),
// today's date
      today = new Date();
today.setHours(11);today.setMinutes(0);today.setSeconds(0);
today.intv=setInterval(checkTime,1000);

function checkTime(){
  const now=new Date();
  if (now>today) {
    demo.textContent="Order today for tomorrow's delivery.";
    clearInterval(today.intv);
  }
  else if (now>(today-1800000)){
    let tsec=Math.floor((today-now)/1000),
        sec=tsec%60,
        min=(tsec-sec)/60;
    
    demo.textContent=`${min} minutes and ${sec} seconds left if you want to order for today's delivery.`;
  } else 
    demo.textContent="Order now for today's delivery!"
}
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```